# Create new record with hash when keys are different from model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a new record with a hash received from a service. However the hash keys do not map directly to the model attributes (all 97 attributes).

For example:

```rb
score_hash = {"ScoreUid"=>"08b65fc5-1cca-45a2", "ScoreIdentifier"=>12345678, "AdjustedScore"=>84}

score_hash.keys
=> ["ScoreUid", "ScoreIdentifier", "AdjustedScore"]

Score.new.attributes.keys
=> ["uid", "service_id", "score"]
```

Is there a nice 'Ruby way' to handle this, without brute force?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create a hash mapping of the field names you're receiving from the third-party service to the column names in the `scores` table. You can then use [`Hash#transform_keys`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys) to transform the keys to the column names using the mapping hash, remove the `nil` key using [`Hash#reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-reject) and use the resulting hash to create a new `Score` record.

```
COLUMN_MAPPING = {
  'ScoreUid' => 'uid',
  'ScoreIdentifier' => 'service_id',
  'AdjustedScore' => 'score',
  # ....
}

score_hash = {"ScoreUid"=>"08b65fc5-1cca-45a2", "ScoreIdentifier"=>12345678, "AdjustedScore"=>84}

attributes = score_hash
  .transform_keys {|k| COLUMN_MAPPING[k] }
  .reject {|k| k.nil? }
#=> {"uid"=>"08b65fc5-1cca-45a2", "service_id"=>12345678, "score"=>84}

score = Score.create!(attributes)
```